# Natural cleaner for oak floor

Tags: cleaning

I have oak wood floors that need significant cleaning. I don't know what specifically is on them, but they're very sticky to walk on.

What's a good natural cleaner to cut the build up and not harm the wood?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've generally heard white vinegar, mixed with water, recommended as the best cleaner for hardwood floors.  Can't get much more natural than that!

According to various sources on the internet (for example http://www.cinhome.com/murphys.html), use of Murphy's Oil Soap can lead to the kind of sticky buildup you're describing.

Comment: Vinegar is excellent.  If your floor has a permeable finish (oil, varnish) use 10% vinegar solution and understand EVERY cleaner containing water in any amount will raise the grain of the wood.  If the finish is impermeable (lacquer, epoxy) use a 30% vinegar solution to dissolve the build-up a lot faster.